# How many binary vectors $y$ of length $n$ such that the inner product of fixed $x$ and $y$ is $0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have a question that I'm trying to solve which is as following:

If $x$ is a fixed vector determine how many binary vectors $y$ of length $n$ do exist such that $\langle x,y\rangle = 0$

> Inner product of two vectors is as following: $$\langle x,y\rangle = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3 + \cdots + x_ny_n$$

I tried and I got as following: $wt(x)2^{n-wt(x)}$ where $wt(x)$ is the number of $1$s in vectors and $n-wt(x)$ is the number of non-zero in $x$. And $2^{n-wt(x)}$ is the number of zeroes in x. It is correct for some values, but not for general! my way to do is to write two vectors of x and y and suppose x is fixed with different number of 0s and 1s. Then, if $x_i=0$, then $y_i=0$ or $y_i=1$ to get $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ So we have two possible values for y if $x_i=0$ and if $x_i=1$, then y must be equal 0. Thus, I calculate the number of zeros in $x$ as ($n-wt(x)$) and powered by $2$ since it has two possible values and times $wt(x)$ because if $x$ has $k$ number of $1$s, then we need $k$ number of $1$s for $y$ to make $\langle x,y\rangle=0$. Thus, we get $wt(x)2^{n-wt(x)}$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vectors orthogonal to $x$ always form an $n-1$ dimensional subspace if $x \neq 0$, and if $x=0$ then the while $n$-dimensional space is orthogonal to it.

An $m$-dimensional space over field of size $q$ has $q^m$ elements. In your case, $q=2$, and

- If $x\neq 0$ then $m=n-1$ and the answer is $2^{n-1}$.
- If $x=0$ then $m=n$ and the answer is $2^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know but it seems incorrect. See the following: if x and y with length 2, then x=00, then there are 4 ways to choose y so $2^n = 2^2$ and not $2^{2-1}, and if x=11, then we have 1 ways to choose y. and if x=01, then there are two ways to choose y.

Comment: @user777 You are right, I missed the case when $x$ is the zero vector. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ok @lisyarus, I just checked your answer for length of 2 and 3 so far and it is really correct so far which is nice answer and I did not expect that. If <x,y> = 1, then we will have the same result, right

Comment: @user777 You are right, for $\langle x, y\rangle=1$ the result is the same. In this case the set of possible $y$ is not a linear subspace, but an affine subspace of appropriate dimension.